# How to terminate running jar file using C#

Tags: java, c#

I have written a code to execute jar file from my C# application , but now I also need to terminate that jar from my C# application. is there any way to do this?

here is my code to start jar from c#.

```
Process myCSharpProcess = new Process();
myJavaProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw";
myJavaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar D:\\DATA\\PROJECT\\LicensingManagement\\Assignment\\JavaLogin.jar \"test\" \"12345\"";
//myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myJavaProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Call `.Kill` if it's not a gui application, or `.StopMainWindow` if it does. Here, [it's in the guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05abh773(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.kill or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.close

Comment: You should also probably use a `using(` clause here.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a static method in the Process class called Stop().

Try `Process.Stop("JavaLogin.jar");`